# How to translate page language using headless chrome / pupeteer before taking a screenshot?

Tags: puppeteer, google-translate, translate, google-chrome-headless

Is it possible to translate page language from english to spanish before taking a screenshot with headless chrome?

If so, how can this be done?

Thank you